# __func__ and logging

Tags: c++, logging, callstack, func

I am implementing a log handler in C++, and it works good and all, however there is one thing which I would find usable and that is where the logger got the output from.

I guess this isn't really a big issue, but I stumbled on the `__func__` identifier, which basically will keep the function name of the current function.

So I have a static function in my Log class called `Write`, it takes a log level, and a vary list. So I would call it as such:

```
Log::Write(LOG_DEBUG, "this is an integer: %d", 10);
```

and it will print:

```
2013-01-02 => 10:12:01.366 [DEBUG]: this is an integer: 10
```

However I was thinking that it could be useful to also have the caller in the message, to produce something like this:

```
2013... => 10:12:... (functionName) [DEBUG]: blah
```

So what I can do (of course) is to add the `__func__` as a parameter to `Log::Write`, however that would mean that any time I call `Log::Write` I need to also send `__func__` which will always be the same and I feel like it should be possible to do it without explicitly saying so.

So what I want is the functionality which would be provided with:

```
Log::Write(LOG_DEBUG, __func__, "message");
```

without needing to explicitly type out **func** every time.

I don't know if this really is possible, the best bet I've got is that there is some way to dereference the caller inside of the function `Write`, it doesn't seem likely that I can just "infer" a parameter like that. But worth asking at least and maybe I can see what options there are.

Thanks.

Comment: This is "traditionally" done with macros.

Comment: There is no `__func__` identifier in C++; it's an addition to C99 which C++ didn't pick up.  I suspect that most C++ compilers will provide it as an extension (because they are also C compilers), but Microsoft doesn't, and my experience suggests that `__FUNCTION__`, despite being part of no standard, is actually more portable.

Comment: I believe that the `__func__` identifier is a C++11 addition and basically it is available in any function and containing the name of the current function. however I might be wrong, but that was my understanding.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is usually done with macros, along with the filename `__FILE__` and line number `__LINE__`.

```
void Log::Write(Level l,
                char const* function,
                char const* file,
                int line,
                char const* format,
                ...);
```

is wrapped into a macro:

```
#define LOG(Level_, Format_, ...) \
    Log::Write(Level_, __func__, __FILE__, __LINE__, Format_, __VA_ARGS__);
```

Note that you may want to "save" some computing by having a check for whether to log at that level or not:

```
// suppose availability of "bool Log::Enabled(Level l)"
#define LOG(Level_, Format_, ...)   \
    while (Log::Enabled(Level_)) {  \
      Log::Write(Level_, __func__, __FILE__, __LINE__, Format_, __VA_ARGS__);  \
      break;  \
    }
```

The use of a `while` instead of `if` is to avoid the dangling else issue.

*Note: you may wish to investigate the use of streams for logging. The issue with `printf` style is that it is not composable. With streams, you can overload `std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream&, X const&)` for any `X` and then only write **once** a method to dump its content in the logs.*

Comment: In this case, the dangling else issue is more easily handled by `if (!Log::isEnabled(level)) ; else ...`.  But better solutions exist, which avoid varargs entirely.  (And `__VAR_ARGS__` is a C++11 feature, and likely not to be available if you're concerned with portability.)

Comment: A lot of great information, thanks! I am actually using ostream so I could as well write `Log::get(level) << "some text"` I am just a bit rusty when it comes to C++ and have a mindset where I am so comfortable with the `printf-type-syntax` I guess. (been working with Objc for the last years but trying to get up to speed using C++). But it's some very good information and I am really glad for it, thanks! (so to be clear... my `Write` function is actually just a wrapper around an `ostream`, getting the vargs and using `get(level)` to produce the logging.

Comment: @JamesKanze: In order to get rid of the varargs, I would favor switching to `ostream` logging. It's just more convenient (for logging).

Comment: @qrikko: both `printf`-style and `ostream`-style have their use. `printf`-style is more amenable to internationalization (thus great to display text to a user) whilst `ostream`-style is more composable; thankfully logging requires composability more than it requires internationalization.

Comment: @MatthieuM. it's really good points, and thanks for taking the time to also point it out. As I said, I kind of did start off with the ostream way, but am just a bit "damaged" or what to call it from Objc where you typically only use vararg-like syntax so I wrapped the ostream logging in a funciton (`Write`) parsing varargs and sending them onto the ostream so just a bad habit I will start using the ostream implementation and even remove the `Log::Write` function since it's really just "syntactical sugar" to me.

Comment: I am however getting a bit stuck on one question here.. couldn't I use default parameters instead of a macro here? like so: `void Log::Write(Level l, char const* function = __func__, char const* file = __FILE__, int line = __LINE__, char const* format, ...);` or am I missing something?

Answer (score 3):

```
#define WRITE_LOG(X,...) Log::Write(LOG_DEBUG, __func__, (X),__VA_ARGS__);
```

Use this macro to write logs instead of the function, and it will automatically add the **func** parameter. As Mat mentions, this is the typical way, I cant think of any way to avoid macros in this case.

Comment: I think that will do, it's pretty clean and does absolutely take care of the "problem", thanks. I didn't think of that and probably should have stayed on google a little while longer, or given it more thought now that I see it.

Comment: @qrikko yup it should work. You can make a different macro for each log level, or modify this one to take 2 parameters, like your log function.

Comment: Note that this requires C++11.  There are better solutions, which don't use varargs at all: basically, `Log::Write` returns a `LogStream` object which has a templated `operator<<` which forwards to the active stream (or not, depending on whether the level of logging is active).

Comment: @JamesKanze I am targeting C++11 and using a lot of the functionality in there, so that is not a problem for me BUT it is a valid point and should be noted! I do also use ostreams in the background and felt more comfortable with varargs (old (and perhaps bad) habit) so the `Log::Write` actually just wraps around another function called `get(short level)` which returns an `ostream` reference, and it's that `ostream` that actually does all the logging.